# Anyway to get around converting tabs to spaces in Notepad++ for Python?

Tags: python, notepad++

So I'm beginning to learn Python and I'm using powershell & Notepad++. The issue I'm having is I noticed when I'm making programs, I get a lot of indentation errors and then I have to go and convert all tabs to spaces, which solves the issue.

My question is, is there anyway to get around this? For instance when you hit tab, it just inserts 4 spaces instead? Because it's really annoying having to consistently do this. I have errors all the time when I have tabs instead of spaces.

Any help is appreciated, thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

There's such an option.

Settings > Preferences > Tab Settings > Replace by space.